# To create column with date datatype in hive table

Tags: date, timestamp, hive

I have created table in HIVE(0.10.0) using values :

```
2012-01-11  17:51   Stockton    Children's Clothing     168.68  Cash
2012-01-11  17:51   Tampa       Health and Beauty       441.08  Amex
............
```

Here date and time are tab separated values and  I need to work on date column, Since Hive doesn't allow "date" datatype ,I have used "TIMESTAMP" for first date column(2012-01-11,...),
 however after creating table it is showing NULL values for first column.

How to solve this? Please guide.

Comment: did you try loading the column as a string and then casting to date..something like `cast(column as date)` Note that this works only for `YYYY-MM-DD` format...

Comment: Yes Its in YYYY-MM-DD format and i tried casting that date but gave me different data :
1969-12-31 16:00:00 09:00 San Jose Men's Clothing 214.05 Amex
1969-12-31 16:00:00 09:00 Fort Worth Women's Clothing 153.57 V

Comment: December 31st of 1969...seems like the date is being reset to start from Unix epoch time...I believe you are defining the data as tab separated and thereby loading the date part into one column and the time into another...

Comment: Yes both date and time are tab separated.How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I loaded the data into a table with all columns defined as `string` and then casted the date value and loaded into another table where the column was defined as `DATE`. It seems to be working without any issues. The only difference is that I am using a Shark version of Hive, and to be honest with you, I am not sure whether there are any profound differences with actual Hive and Shark Hive.

**Data:**

```
hduser2@ws-25:~$ more test.txt 
2010-01-05  17:51   Visakh
2013-02-16  09:31   Nair
```

**Code:**

```
[localhost:12345] shark>  create table test_time(dt string, tm string, nm string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;
Time taken (including network latency): 0.089 seconds
[localhost:12345] shark> describe test_time;
dt  string  
tm  string  
nm  string  
Time taken (including network latency): 0.06 seconds
[localhost:12345] shark> load data local inpath '/home/hduser2/test.txt' overwrite into table test_time;                                                   
Time taken (including network latency): 0.124 seconds
[localhost:12345] shark> select * from test_time;
2010-01-05  17:51   Visakh
2013-02-16  09:31   Nair
Time taken (including network latency): 0.397 seconds
[localhost:12345] shark> select cast(dt as date) from test_time;
2010-01-05
2013-02-16
Time taken (including network latency): 0.399 seconds
[localhost:12345] shark> create table test_date as select cast(dt as date) from test_time;
Time taken (including network latency): 0.71 seconds
[localhost:12345] shark> select * from test_date;
2010-01-05
2013-02-16
Time taken (including network latency): 0.366 seconds
[localhost:12345] shark>
```

If you are using `TIMESTAMP`, then you could try something in the lines of concatenating the date and time strings and then casting them.

```
create table test_1 as select cast(concat(dt,' ', tm,':00') as string) as ts from test_time;

select cast(ts as timestamp) from test_1;
```

Comment: I have used timestamp because hive 0.10.0 doesn't support date.

Comment: @ashwini have updated my answer to get the data loaded as `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 4):

It works fine for me by using load command from beeline side.

Data:

```
[root@hostname workspace]# more timedata 
buy,1977-03-12 06:30:23
sell,1989-05-23 07:23:12
```

creating table statement:

```
create table mytime(id string ,t timestamp) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

And loading data statement:

```
load data local inpath '/root/workspace/timedata' overwrite into table mytime;
```

Table structure:

```
describe mytime;      
+-----------+------------+----------+--+
| col_name  | data_type  | comment  |
+-----------+------------+----------+--+
| id        | string     |          |
| t         | timestamp  |          |
+-----------+------------+----------+--+
```

result of querying:

```
select * from mytime;                                                                     
+------------+------------------------+--+
| mytime.id  |       mytime.t        |
+------------+------------------------+--+
| buy        | 1977-03-12 06:30:23.0  |
| sell       | 1989-05-23 07:23:12.0  |
+------------+------------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache [Hive Data Types](http://beyondcorner.com/learn-apache-hive/apache-hive-data-types/) are very important for query language and data modeling (representation of the data structures in a table for a company’s database).
It is necessary to know about the data types and its usage to defining the table column types.
There are mainly two types of Apache [Hive Data Types](http://beyondcorner.com/learn-apache-hive/apache-hive-data-types/). They are,
Primitive Data types
Complex Data types
Will discuss about Complex data types,
Complex Data types further classified into four types. They are explained below,

2.1 ARRAY
It is an ordered collection of fields.
The fields must all be of the same type
Syntax: ARRAY

Example: array (1, 4)

2.2 MAP
It is an unordered collection of key-value pairs.
Keys must be primitives,values may be any type.
Syntax: MAP

Example: map(‘a’,1,’c’,3)

2.3 STRUCT
It is a collection of elements of different types.
Syntax: STRUCT

Example: struct(‘a’, 1 1.0)

2.4 UNION
It is a collection of Heterogeneous data types.
Syntax: UNIONTYPE

Example: create_union(1, ‘a’, 63)